# Display image blobs, possible encoding error

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a form where users can upload images to my MySQL database. The table has three columns: `id`, `name` and `image`. `Image` is a blob column with the default settings. I'm able to store the image data, but when I fetch the data and try to display it on the web page, I just get a broken image (in this case it's a jpeg file).

I suspect something has gone wrong with the encoding somewhere. My upload.php file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. This is my upload code:

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

$insert = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO images VALUES(:id,:name,:image)');
$insert->bindValue(':id', '');
$insert->bindParam(':name', $image_name);
$insert->bindParam(':image', $image);
$insert->execute();
```

And this is where I try to display the image.

```
$select = $conn->prepare('SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = 2');
$select->execute();

$display = $select->fetch();

echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode( $display['image'] ) . '" />';
```

I watched a video tutorial on blobs in MySQL, where the blob column had the `binary`attribute. However, when I try to create a column like that, I get an error 1064. I don't even know it that has got anything to do with this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using `addslashes()` with prepared statements (not that that's your issue here).

By default `->bindParam()` defaults to type `PDO::PARAM_STR`, so you'll need to specify that the data you're passing is not a string.

Try:

```
$insert->bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

Storing binary data in a database can lead to all sorts of issues too. I'd recommend storing the file to disk and just storing the path to it in the DB - it has all sorts of advantages.

Comment: It works! Although, the image is being cropped for some reason. Perhaps that is one of the issues that you mentioned. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  It'd be very hard to crop an image accidentally without using a graphics library so I suspect it's something in the HTML/display of the page.

Comment: Oh ok. Just of curiosity, what kind of issues does storing binary data in a database have?

Comment: Depending on storage engines and quantity of data, you can end up wit a very bloated database. A filesystem is good for storing files and usually many times cheaper in terms of actual cost and performance.  You also can't stream files from a database - e.g. using the system's **sendfile()** function, which can be important when you don't want to eat all of PHP's memory just reading a file.